# Why is net framework 4.5 azure deployment ignoring app service connection strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-devops

Background:

I am moving one of our net framework 4.5 projects into a DevOps pipeline which will deploy to our App service.

In order to make sure none of the application secrets are copied into source control I have updated the *Web.config* connections strings as so:

`<connectionStrings configSource="connectionStrings.config"></connectionStrings>`

The *connectionStrings.config* is not committed to source control. Instead, we have an example version without a valid string that is in source control, detailed here:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <clear/>
  <add name="EFDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=XXXXX\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=XXXXX;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

In the Azure App service we have the correct Connection string set.

[image: Azure connection string]

In the pipeline, the app is building successfully but after it is deployed the app is not using the connection string specified in the Azure App service, and is throwing the following error:

`The connection name 'LocalSqlServer' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty.`

Question(s):

Why is the app ignoring the App service environment variable?

I was under the impression that the connection strings set in Azure would take precedence. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I see a conflict there, in the settings you have added as "EFDbContext" but in the code you are searching for LocalSqlServer. Check if you have the same name in the appsettings as well

Comment: There is no LocalSqlServer reference in the codebase. I have added the connection string file that is in source control to OP. My suspicion is that this is being used instead of the environment variables set in Azure

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Sajeetharan, the issue is your code base is referencing this LocalSqlServer.  [Per Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common):

> For ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core developers, setting connection strings in
>   App Service are like setting them in  in
>   Web.config, but the values you set in App Service override the ones in
>   Web.config. You can keep development settings (for example, a database
>   file) in Web.config and production secrets (for example, SQL Database
>   credentials) safely in App Service. The same code uses your
>   development settings when you debug locally, and it uses your
>   production secrets when deployed to Azure.

I'd recommend inspecting the files deployed within the App Service to confirm.  This can be done via either the [Kudoor the App Service Editor](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36467.understanding-the-azure-app-service-editor.aspx) in the Portal.